# Blackberry SDK: Read SMS folders

Tags: java, blackberry

is it possible to read all sent/received SMS (and possibly even MMS) in a BlackBerry app?

Even if it's 5.0+ only... I need this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can listen for incoming SMS messages but you can't read the ones that are already there.  You could listen for all messages and then save them somewhere but that's hardly an ideal solution.  [Here's some info on listening for messages.](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_listen_for_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1357551&vernum=0)

Comment: but, then, how do apps like http://www.getempower.com/product.php?appid=21&n=Empower-Threaded-SMS-for-BlackBerry work???

Comment: they probably set up a listener in the background (as Jonathan described) and store the SMS messages in their own database, to be displayed in a "threaded" fashion when you run the GUI app